# Interactive image with IE support

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have a interactive image that works perfectly fine in all other browsers than Internet Explorer, but I need it to work there as well...

How can I make this javascript code support newer and older IE browsers?

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    hideDiv(e);
});


$( document ).ready(function( ) {
$( "#ab-1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#a-1" ).show( "fade" );
});

$( "#ab-2" ).click(function() {
  $( "#a-2" ).show( "fade" );
});

$( "#ab-3" ).click(function() {
  $( "#a-3" ).show( "fade" );
});

});

function hideDiv(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.ansatt') && !$(e.target).parents().is('.ansatt')) {
        $('.ansatt').hide( );
    $('.ansatt-info').show () ;
    }
}
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    hideDiv(e);
});
```

Comment: That is not a shock, it always happens in older version of IE!

Comment: For a fully IE support you should check for [e.srcElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is used instead of `e.target`. If you can post some HTML code it will be easier to create a test page..

Comment: @Jonathan
    <div id="ansatt-bildet">
    <p><img alt="" src="http://ysst.no/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/interactive-image.png" width="100%"></p>
    <div class="ab" id="ab-1"></div>
    <div class="ansatt" id="a-1">
    <p class="navn">Name</p>
    <p class="stilling">Position</p>
    <p class="mailweb">phone / mail@adress.com / website.com</p>
    </div>
    </div>

Comment: When asking IE-related questions, please *always* specify which IE versions you're having trouble with. The same goes for jQuery versions (especially in conjunction with IE, since some jQuery versions don't work with older IE versions). Also please give a bit more detail about the problem: just saying "*it works perfecly in other browsers but not IE*" isn't a very good description; what about it doesn't work? is it failing completely or just not quite perfect? What error messages do you get? What other symptoms? Is it the same across all IE versions?

Comment: @Spudley : No IE is handeling the javascript, and I am using the latest stabile version of jQuery. So in detail; the script isn't worinkg in IE, and there is no error messages.

Comment: @MagnusØstrem - there are two "latest" versions of jQuery. If you want to support old IE versions, you need to use jQuery v1.x, not v2.x. This is why it's important to specify the jQuery version.

Comment: If you're using `$( document ).ready`, you should put *all* your event handling functions into it: Try moving your `.on()` block into your `.ready()` block.